# Updating Vignettes in R

Tags: r, cran, vignette

I found a mistake in a vignette I wrote for my R package. To re-upload the vignette, do I need to resubmit the entire package to CRAN? I'm thinking of this from the CRAN side that I don't want to make someone have to review my entire package when it's just a pdf file that is changing. Or maybe it's not so bad for the CRAN reviewers?

Answer (score 1):

You might get the anger of Kurt Hornik or Prof. Ripley ;-) . But besides there is no alternative option. I would consider the severity of your mistake and maybe ship it with the next update. If you want to actually resubmit the package, you can mention in the comment field, that this is the only change. Most of the checks run fully automatic anyways.